# Generic constraint object with property string

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints

I have a generic function and I only want the properties string from the object:

```js
type StringProps<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T];

public someFunction<T extends { [key in string]: string }>(list: T[], props: StringProps<T>[]): void {
  const foo: string[] = list.flatMap(item => props.map(prop => item[prop]));
}
```

This works when T is an object with properties of type string only. But it fails when the object has other types. I could change the constraint to: `[key in string]: any` but I'd like to avoid using any as much as possible (even though any here wouldn't matter much.

In short: how can I create a constraint to work with `someFunction` with an object looking like this:

```
{
  age?: number,
  name?: string,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, all you need to do is change:

```js
// from
function someFunction<T extends { [key in string]: string }>() {}

// to:
function someFunction<T extends { [key in string]: any }>() {}
```

you can replace `any` with any constraints you have on the shape of the object.

The reason for this is that you are telling typescript that the generic `T` must extend `key: string` and `value: string` and nothing else. As a result when you give it a number typescript will give you with error along the lines of `value: string` is not assignable to `value: string | number`.

So simply changing it from `value: string` to `any` or whatever the constraint should be fixes the issue.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJRBvW)

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned above, I was hoping for a solution without any though, but I think it's not possible then.

Comment: I mean as I mentioned you don't have to put `any` you can change that to be whatever you want. e.g. if you want only `string` and `number` then you can have `string | number` but unfortunately you will have to be specific.